# Excel - how to select a range in VBA using an expression like VLOOPUP?

Tags: excel, vba, range, vlookup

I need to create a macro button, which adds +1 value to a cell.

The problem is, the correct cell should be chosen from a table, using a VLOOKUP function, like this one:
VLOOKUP(A38;$A$50:$Q$59;6)

How can I program this in VBA?

Thanks alot!!

Comment: Add your code attempt.

Comment: SO is not intended to be a free code-writing service. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

[VLookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup) returns a value, to return a cell reference use [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find). Assuming  A38 and the lookup range $A$50:$Q$59 is on Sheet1 then try

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddOne()
    
    Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range, v
    
    v = Sheet1.Range("A38")
    Set rngSearch = Sheet1.Range("A50:A59")
    
    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(v, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "'" & v & "' not found in range " & rngSearch.Address, vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "'" & v & "' found at range " & rngFound.Address
        'increment column F
        rngFound.Offset(0, 5) = rngFound.Offset(0, 5) + 1
    End If

End Sub
```